# grails linking a cart object to a user object

Tags: grails

Good day. I am new to grails and I have to design a music-shopping type app. I have a Cart domain and a User domain and what I'm trying to do is when I create a new User object I want to have a new Cart object created too that links to said User object in the User. I'm using static scaffolding so I want to do this in the User/save action. Here's my code:

```
class Cart {
    String item
    Integer quantity
    BigDecimal price
    String type
    Integer typeId
    User user
    static constraints = {
        type nullable:false, blank:false, inList:["Album", "Song", "Empty"]
        typeId nullable:false, blank:false
    }
}

class User {
    String username
    String password
    String fName
    String lName
    String email
    static constraints = {
        username(nullable : false, blank : false, minSize : 1)
        password(nullable : false, blank : false, minSize : 1)
        fName(nullable : false, blank : false, minSize : 1)
        lName(nullable : false, blank : false, minSize : 1)
        email(nullable : false, blank : false, email : true)
    }
}

class UserController {
    //static scaffolded code (index, show, create, etc.)
    @Transactional
    def save(User userInstance){     //This whole method is also generated with scaffolding 
        if (userInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond userInstance.errors, view: 'create'
            return
        }

        userInstance.save flush: true

        //This is what I've been trying to do but it doesn't work and I don't know why :(
        def myCart = new Cart(user:userInstance, item:'empty item', quantity:0, price:0, total:0, type:'Empty', typeId:0).save(flush:true)

        //Rest of the generated code
    }
    //More generated code
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 bugs in Cart class.
First: update typeID to typeId
Second: type should be String, not BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) explains well on how to do cascading in Grails.

> Cascading determines what type of actions, when applied to a domain instance, also apply to the relations of that instance.

According to how the cascading goes, I think it makes more sense that you have a Cart object in User class and use belongsTo to let Grails know the Cart is saved or deleted with the User.